# How to re-display the last of type element on screen sizing in CSS?

Tags: html, css

First issue is seen here:[450px to 760px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEheR.png)

I can't embed pics yet but looks like the link works, my apologies. You can see though that the last li has the border-right hidden. That is as intended. Here is the code for that screen sizing:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 450px){       
    nav li{
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 1px solid #f6dde3;
        padding-right: 3px;
    }   
    nav li:last-of-type{
        border-right: hidden;
    }
}
```

The issue is when I size above 760px I lose the right border. I'm attempting to make a simple button-like look. Here is a pic:
[>760px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A728e.png)
You can see the last box the border-right is still hidden. Here is the media query code for larger screen sizes:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 760px){   
    nav li{
        padding-right: none;
    }   
    nav ul li ul li{
        border: 1px solid #f6dde3;
        width: 140px;
    }   
}
```

I've tried to do a :last of type with nav li and show the border-right as visible or block, inline etc. If I remove the last of type on the >450px it not only shows the border of the button box but also the extra created border on just the last li. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><span id="menulabel">MENU</span>           
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="adoptapet.html">adopt a pet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">community</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">news</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The MENU button is hidden on anything larger than 450px, I removed it and a couple other things from the code for a cleaner look that would have no affect on this issue. Thanks for any insights! I've been reading up on screen sizing and have seen several other issues close to this one but can't find the little nugget that I'm sure is simple for this.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a `nav li li:last-of-type` to avoid an extra line as well as defining the `border-right` as a `1px solid`. It was a bandaid attempt shot in the dark but it worked.